# Figures are messed up when opening PDF in Adobe Reader

Tags: graphics, pdf, adobe, jpeg

I compile my tex file using WinEdt 7.0. Many of the figures in the generated pdf are messed up if the pdf is opened in Adobe, but the figures are totally fine in the preview (I use SumatraPDF) or if I open the pdf in Chrome. My figures are jpg images. I also tried one figure to png but it didn't work. I took a screenshot of a problematic figure in Adbobe and in Chrome respectively as below. Does anyone know if it's because of the figure, compiler, or Adobe Reader? And how can I fix this problem?

[image: This is when viewed in Adobe Reader.]

[image: This is when viewed in Chrome.]

Comment: It is because of jpg format. Use a vector format like png or pdf.

Comment: I regenerated my figures in Microsoft Visio in png format and it solves my problem! Thank you!

Comment: @HarishKumar: png is not a vector format.

Comment: It could be a resolution issue.  I noticed that when I put a jpeg into a pdf that one can zoom in to the limits of the jpeg resolution.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: What steps do you use to produce your PDF?